# Как найти минимальную цену на заданный товар коллекции с помощью типизированного итератора?

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть четыре класса.
Первый класс товаров.

```
class Good {
    String name;
    double price;

    public Good(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Второй класс магазин.

```
class OnlineStore {
    String name;
    List<Good> goods;

    public OnlineStore(String name, List<Good> list) {
        this.name = name;
        this.goods = list;
    }
}
```

Третий класс сервис поиска товаров.

```
class ProductSearchSrvice {
    List<OnlineStore> store;

    public ProductSearchSrvice(List<OnlineStore> store) {
        if(store.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

И последний класс, где все происходит.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Good Tuner = new Good("Tuner", 350.0);
        Good Cable_HDMI = new Good("Cable HDMI", 29.6);
        Good Control_panel = new Good("Cable HDMI", 150.5);
        Good Tuner_1 = new Good("Tuner", 1323.0);
        Good Cable_HDMI_1 = new Good("Control_panel", 470.0);
        Good Control_panel_1 = new Good("Control_panel", 617.0);
        Good Tuner_2 = new Good("Tuner", 567.89);
        Good Cable_HDMI_2 = new Good("Cable_HDMI", 249.5);
        Good Control_panel_2 = new Good("Control_panel", 850.0);
        ArrayList listOfMirElectroniki = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList listOfHIKVISION = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList listOfOLX = new ArrayList();
        listOfMirElectroniki.add(Tuner);
        listOfMirElectroniki.add(Cable_HDMI);
        listOfMirElectroniki.add(Control_panel);
        listOfHIKVISION.add(Tuner_1);
        listOfHIKVISION.add(Cable_HDMI_1);
        listOfHIKVISION.add(Control_panel_1);
        listOfOLX.add(Tuner_2);
        listOfOLX.add(Cable_HDMI_2);
        listOfOLX.add(Control_panel_2);
        OnlineStore MirElecroniki = new OnlineStore("Mir Electroniki", listOfMirElectroniki);
        OnlineStore HIKVISIOB = new OnlineStore("HIKVISION", listOfHIKVISION);
        OnlineStore OLX = new OnlineStore("OLX", listOfOLX);
}
```

Как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Не используйте `raw types` в дженериках, Вместо `ArrayList someList = new ArrayList();` пишите `ArrayList<Good> someList = new ArrayList<>();`
2. В конструкторе `ProductSearchService` после проверки на пустоту списка, все же сделайте присвоение `this.store = store;`
3. Также сделайте все поля в своих классах `private` и добавьте `get` методы для них
4. Ну и сам метод поиска минимальной цены по товару (с использованием стримов):

   ```
   public double findMinPriceByGoodName(String goodName) {
       return store.stream()
           .flatMap(onlineStore -> onlineStore.getGoods().stream())
           .filter(good -> good.getName().equals(goodName))
           .min(Comparator.comparing(Good::getPrice)).get().getPrice();
   }
   ```
5. Если стримы сложно, вот тот же метод с циклом:

   ```
   public double findMinPriceByGoodName(String goodName) {

       double result = 0;
       for (OnlineStore onlineStore : store) {
           for (Good good : onlineStore.getGoods()) {
               if (good.getName().equals(goodName)) {
                   if (good.getPrice() < result || result == 0) {
                       result = good.getPrice();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```
6. Если есть требование сделать именно с помощью `Iterator` (что конечно менее читаемо и не рекомендуется для использования), в целях изучения например, то вот с итератором:

   ```
   public double findMinPriceByGoodName(String goodName) {

       double result = 0;
       for (Iterator<OnlineStore> iterator = store.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
           OnlineStore onlineStore = iterator.next();
           for (Iterator<Good> iterator1 = onlineStore.getGoods().iterator(); iterator1.hasNext(); ) {
               Good good = iterator1.next();
               if (good.getName().equals(goodName)) {
                   if (good.getPrice() < result || result == 0) {
                       result = good.getPrice();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

Теперь создаем наш сервис (не забыв передать в конструктор список магазинов) и вызываем метод:

```
List<OnlineStore> stores = new ArrayList<>();
stores.add(MirElecroniki);
stores.add(HIKVISIOB);
stores.add(OLX);

ProductSearchService service = new ProductSearchService(stores);

double minPrice = service.findMinPriceByGoodName("Tuner");
System.out.println("Min price for Tuner" + minPrice);
```

Comment: Почему это итератор не рекомендуется для использования? Кем не рекомендуется? Зачем он тогда нужен?

Comment: Такой вопрос. А в каких классах надо прописывать 6 и созданный сервис?

Comment: У меня все классы в разных файлах, не в одном.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Потому что он менее читаем и очевидно в такой простой задаче предпочтительнее использовать `for`. Не рекомендуется использовать потому что на его замену в версии джава1.5 были введены `for-each` циклы. А итератор, если не ошибаюсь есть с версии 1.2.  Тем не менее есть задачи, где он необходим, например удаления елементов из коллекции.

Comment: @НастяГрант метод `findMinPriceByGoodName` прописывать в классе `ProductSearchService`. Созданный сервис, очевидно, в `main`

Comment: Еще такой вопрос.У меня возникла ошибка и я не могу понять почему. Ошибка на фото выше. Как её исправить?

Comment: @НастяГрант В MirElecroniki пропущена "t". HIKVISIOB в конце "N"

Comment: А может кто-то построчно объяснить, что происходит в public double findMinPriceByGoodName(String goodName)?